# CSS transitions through Ember.js Views: The "Ember" way to do it?

Tags: ember.js

I'm using the {{bind-attr}} helper to bind a class name to an element for the purposes of transitions (in css), and setting the values in the controller on 'didInsertElement' seems to short circuit the transition, even with delays in my CSS to prevent it. Though, the end-state of the transition is rendered.

I've tried Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender') which seems to do the trick, but isn't quite what I want from a 'clarity' standpoint.

Is there a hook (or a way to create one, outside of an uggo setTimeout call) that fires AFTER an element has been inserted into the dom and is effectively finished rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender')`. But you can do it more elegantly by doing the following. Now **all of your Views have the hook afterRenderEvent**. This should suffice from a clarity standpoint, right?

```
Ember.View.reopen({
  didInsertElement : function(){
    this._super();
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, this.afterRenderEvent);
  },
  afterRenderEvent : function(){
    // implement this hook in your own subclasses and run your jQuery logic there
  }
});
```

PS: This snippet is taken from a post on my [blog](http://mavilein.github.io/javascript/2013/08/01/Ember-JS-After-Render-Event/), where i explain the approach more in detail.

Comment: thanks, this seems to work pretty well!  Now if only there was a hook for the pre-transitionTo events to teardown the UI

Comment: What do you mean by pre-transitionTo events?

Comment: For me in 1.0.0, css transitions still are not fired unless I add a 1ms settimeout in the afterRender hook, as I detailed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838405/why-is-ember-run-afterrender-not-working-for-css-transitions)

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party, but we needed css animations in ember-paper, so I created an ember addon that makes it possible to transition components (just like ng-animate and React Animation) with only css.

https://github.com/peec/ember-css-transitions