# Why is Ember.run afterRender not working for CSS transitions?

Tags: ember.js, css-transitions

From my understanding, one way to work with CSS transitions is to use `Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender')`

However, for me it is not working without adding a timeout. This is in Ember 1.0.0

```
View = Em.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, 'animateModalOpen');
  },

  animateModalOpen: function() {
    // this does not work - modal gets styles from class "in" with no transition
    $('.modal').addClass('in');

    // this does work, the transition is fired
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.modal').addClass('in');
      }, 1);
    }
  },
});
```

Is this something that used to work and just doesn't anymore, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Ember.run.next` has worked very well for me on this type of thing.

```
didInsertElement: function() {
  Ember.run.next(this, this.animateModalOpen);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. After reading the documentation more carefully it is clear that afterRender is after rendering DOM elements but before final insertion, thus ok for dimensional calculations etc., but too soon for css transitions.

Comment: Good to know.  Thanks for posting the follow up.

Comment: I was adding a CSS class to a DOM element via Ember.run.schedule. It worked while I was stepping through code, but then, at one step, the element must have been re-rendered and the class I added was gone. Changing Ember.run.schedule to Ember.run.next fixed that issue for me.