# Animating between routes in Ember

Tags: jquery, animation, ember.js

I'm trying to animate transitions between routes and I'd like to use jQuery, rather than the CSS3 animations in [ember-animated-outlet](https://github.com/billysbilling/ember-animated-outlet).

So far, I've replaced the `{{link-to}}` helpers with actions that take a route as a parameter. I define this action (which fades out everything in the main `{{outlet}}`, then calls `transitionToRoute()`) in the relevant controller. Then I use the `afterModel` hook at the new route to fade the main `{{outlet}}` back in.

Template:

```
<li><a href="#/posts" {{action goToRoute 'posts'}}>Posts</a></li>
```

Controller:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        goToRoute: function(route) {
            var that = this;
            $('.mainoutlet').fadeTo(200, 0, function() {
                that.transitionToRoute(route);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Route:

```
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    afterModel: function() {
        $('.mainoutlet').fadeTo(200, 1);
    }
});
```

This all works well, until I click the 'Posts' link when I'm already at the posts route. I'm not sure whether this is because `transitionToRoute()` isn't called if you're already at the route you're trying to transition to (even though it appears to be logged), or if the `afterModel` hook isn't called a second time (perhaps both).

I've tried (somewhat unsuccessfully) to test the route parameter against the `currentPath` and only fade out the main `{{outlet}}` if they're different, to ensure that a transition is actually going to happen. Is there another way to make sure a method is called at the `PostsRoute`, regardless of whether or not I'm already at that route? Or indeed a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of use afterModel hooks, is more easy to use the `afterRender` queue. Like the following:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    _showOutletWithTransition: function() {
        $('.mainoutlet').fadeTo(200, 1);
    },
    actions: {
        goToRoute: function(route) { 
            var that = this;
            $('.mainoutlet').fadeTo(200, 0, function() {
                Ember.run(function() {
                    that.transitionToRoute(route);
                });                
                Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', that._showOutletWithTransition);
            });            
        }
    }
});
```

The afterRender queue is executed when all view rendering is performed, and present in the dom. This will fit well your case.

Here is a jsfiddle with this working http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/HgKy3/

I hope it helps

Comment: Nice! Does it make a difference whether or not `that.transitionToRoute()` occurs within a RunLoop?

Comment: It's a good idea to put the Ember.run() in a callback that isn't ember aware, like the fadeTo method. To prevent some weird errors.

Comment: are you sure afterRender is after insertion? The wording in the docs lead me to believe it is after rendering but before insertion. And my experience with firing css transitions in View.didInsertElement is that I have to use Ember.run.next, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838405/why-is-ember-run-afterrender-not-working-for-css-transitions)

Comment: however, your fiddle does work for me too. Is there a difference between `Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender'` in `View.didInsertElement` vs. in a controller action?

Comment: The ordering in `Ember.run.queues` at the moment is "sync", "actions", "routerTransitions", "render", "afterRender", "destroy", so `afterRender` will be always called, after `render` queue. The $().appendTo is performed in the render queue https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-views/lib/views/view.js#L1484, so in the afterRender, you will have the elements present in the dom. All of this is consistent with the ember system, but some assync codes like jQuery.fadeTo, isn't ember aware.

Comment: ... So the ordering is unexpected, because it will run on browser queue, this will give some explanation about it http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/. Ember.run.later will use the setTimeout, so some times, using it after a css transition can work.